# Select text interval in a grid without interruptions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

I want to click and select a interval of a text using Jquery Selectable, but if this sentence has a line, it breaks the interval.

I guess I am missing some parameter on the

```
$( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
```

I expect to click on "Hello" and drag to "Programmers" selecting the interval "Helly my lovely World of Programmers" instead of "Hello of Programmers".

{Hello my lovely World 
of Programmers} that helps
to each other

instead of 
{Hello} my lovely World 
{of Programmers} that helps
to each other

https://jsfiddle.net/cristianroethig/xh8jk19e/

Comment: Hi @cristian Selectable and Draggabletwo different method so please explain what you want. or you can use visit on this link for further information https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: hi @Videsh I am writing a kind of text marker, where I select part of a text and send it to a database. But using this example (https://jsfiddle.net/cristianroethig/xh8jk19e/) and try to select a interval from two different lines, part of the text wont be selected. Is there a parameter to make it possible? (I already saw the documentation :( )

Comment: i get some research for your case but i didn't found any kind of parameter for this yes you can select multiple by press ctrl button and select them, but is case of drag this will work with their default functionality.  https://jsfiddle.net/wy7sneto/

Thank You.

Comment: hi @VIdeshi I decided to get rid of JQuery Selectable and wrote in chaotic JQuery :) thanks for the help